# SetFocus is getting ignored - Why?

Tags: vba, combobox, setfocus

I have 2 fields - txtTR1_Unit and cmbTR2_Unit.  Together, these 2 fields represent the total UNIT.
cmbTR2_Unit has a list of unique values that when selected - txtTR1_Unit automatically gets the related value.

I've created a function called Tier1from2  - that accepts a 'string' and returns the related Tier1 value.

So when I update cmbTR2_Unit  in my After_Update event, I'd like to automatically tab to the next field. - Another combo box.  I figured that I shouldn't need to set any focus, because it would automatically go to the next field after updating.

txtTR1 gets updated just as expected from my Function, but then it just sits there and won't go to the next field.  So I have attempted to 'SetFocus' to the next field after the update.

Still no go.  What did I miss??

```
 Private Sub cmbTR2_UNIT_AfterUpdate()
        If Len(Me.cmbTR2_UNIT.Value) <> 0 Then
         Me.txtTR1_UNIT.Value = Tier1From2(Me.cmbTR2_UNIT.Text)
        'cmb_CostCenter.setfocus  - 'this doesn't seem necessary - but it doesn't work anyway.

        End If

    End Sub
```

As a test I tried removing the function "Tier1From2(Me.cmbTR2_UNIT.text)" simply hard coding the word 'RESULT' in txtTR1_UNIT and it works without a hitch. I know I used to write a more simple function but I haven't touched VBA in awhile - How can I simplify this function:

```
Private Function Tier1From2(strTier2 As String) As String

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qUNIT_HUB")

    strQry = "SELECT Tier1_Unit, Tier2_Unit " & _
    " FROM LTBL_Cost_Collector " & _
    " GROUP BY Tier1_Unit, Tier2_Unit " & _
    " HAVING (((Tier2_Unit) = '" & strTier2 & "'));"


    qdf.SQL = strQry
    db.QueryDefs.Refresh

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQry)


    Tier1From2 = rs![Tier1_Unit]

    Set db = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set Recordset = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: Have you set the tab order the controls such that they follow each other in the hierarchy?  If you don't, the default tab order is the order of creation and may not be what you expect.

Comment: Is cmb_CostCenter in a Frame or Multipage?

Comment: Yes, tab order has been set.  I have set txtTR1_Unit as "TabStop: NO",  cmb_CostCenter is currently just on the same form.  My concern is that when I select a value from cmbTR2_Unit and press the tab key, I get that bell sound that windows makes when it's inappropriate.  As if Tab is not available.  Yet, if I don't select a value, I can tab right through with no problems.  Version of MS Access is 2007.

Comment: Edited my question. Problem solved - Somthing about the db.querydefs.refresh was causing the field to lose it's focus.I changed my function so that it uses the 'Dynaset' option of a Recordset instead of QueryDefinition. Somthing about the db.querydefs.refresh was causing the field to lose it's focus. Somthing about the db.querydefs.refresh was causing the field to lose it's focus.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that something in this function was causing the field and form to loose focus. db.QueryDefs.refresh perhaps?  The solution was to update my Function as follows

```
Private Function Tier1From2(strTier2 As String) As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strTier1 As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "SELECT Tier1_Unit, Tier2_Unit " & _
    " FROM LTBL_Cost_Collector " & _
    " GROUP BY Tier1_Unit, Tier2_Unit " & _
    " HAVING (((Tier2_Unit) = '" & strTier2 & "'));"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    strTier1 = rs!Tier1_Unit

      Set rs = Nothing
      Set db = Nothing

    Tier1From2 = strTier1
End Function
```

This worked without a hitch.